# How can i add customize background color of card component of bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, customization, background-color

[As i have tried to add custom color but couldn't so now  i want to add a custom background color of div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjYjh.png)

Comment: Please provide the code always as text, not image. Try also to be more precise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use style property like following. You can also pass a hexadecimal value like #FFFFFF:

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}><div>
```